# Where can I ask question about blogging concept?

Tags: discussion

Where can I ask a question regarding my ideas for blog posts (of course technical, programming blog).

I have a postX - what should be changed, improved, etc... ?

Is there something like https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ but for technical/programming articles?

Comment: I don't think a "review my blog" site exists on the SE network.

Comment: [Whiteboard chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard) looks like an appropriate place for this kind stuff

Answer (score 5):

For writing critiques and questions on technical writing, the closer fit within the Stack Exchange universe is [Writers Stack Exchange](https://writers.stackexchange.com/). From the [site's help center](https://writers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> **What topics can I ask about here?**
>
> Questions on these topics are welcome here:
>
> ...
>
> - A writing critique, [properly scoped and framed](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work) (If you find those guidelines unclear, or need a quick summary, [this chart](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/488/clarification-of-critique-guidelines/489#489) will help)

However, I should warn you that I'm not intimately familiar with the site and I may be completely wrong when I'm saying that your questions would be welcomed there. You should read the rest of the article and the scope guidelines thoroughly, and decide on your own if the site is what you are looking for. Additionally, it wouldn't hurt if you stopped by the [site's main chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/168/the-overlook-hotel) and ask its regulars for further guidance.

If, on the other hand, what you are looking for is feedback and general discussion for your *programming* blog post ideas, then the more appropriate place would be our own chat room, [The Whiteboard](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard).